# Content Management System concept and sample code?

Tags: php, content-management-system

Hi it's my first time asking here in stack overflow since i've been lurking alot in this place learning and understanding the codes

I'm kinda having a hard time learning and knowing what is really a CMS?? (i've done my homework by asking google-sensei about it and learned that its more into update/edit /add dynamically in a website but my problem is i can't see some codes to look REFERENCE into.. )

i would gladly appreciate if anyone could help me and i'm willing to learn stuffs like this

By the way my proficiency in php coding is beginner to -intermediate i guess.

THank you!

Comment: A decent CMS is a complex thing; you probably don't want to try writing one as a beginner/intermediate.  A good starting point would be to look at some existing free ones, like Drupal or Joomla.

Comment: thnx @Wyzard so it would be very hard for me to see a simple CMS working in codes?... i mean are there any forums that teaches you how to make it?(sorri for the bad english)

Comment: If you want to understand what a CMS *is*, looking at something like Wordpress or Drupal would be helpful because they're mature, robust projects.  If you want to write your own, there are smaller free CMSes that might be easier for studying code.  But it'll be a big project.  If your goal is to build a useful website, you're probably better off using an existing CMS than writing your own.

Comment: thank you @Wyzard that was alot of insight thanks

Answer (score 1):

**CMS** means **Content Management System**. This means CMS is the system used for managing content. You usually use it for the web page to add, edit and remove... content.

You can even take a look at [tag summary on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cms):

> CMS stands for Content Management System. A CMS is a platform used to build websites that are easily edited by multiple users.

Googling it shows such results:

- [Wikipedia article on Content Management System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system),

There are many CMSes, for example [Drupal](http://drupal.org/), [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/), [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/) (all PHP-based), [Django CMS](https://www.django-cms.org/), [Plone](http://plone.org/) (Python-based) and so on...

Comment: oh thanks so it would be very hard to see a simple working CMS at work? @Tadeck

Comment: @MarkJasonGalarpe: Go to http://www.opensourcecms.com/ and see various demos they have there. There are plenty of them.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you'd want to avoid Drupal, Wordpress, Joomla, etc until you understand PHP/MySQL yourself.  I'm sure others will disagree with me, but I find those systems to be too convoluted and overly complex for most applications.

Start with some basics, search google for tutorials, etc then work yourself into a CMS.  It can be done, but you have to start with the basics.

Comment: WordPress isn't convoluted. Wordpress will help the OP get a site off the ground. Editing the themes, and working with plugins will provide the OP with an opportunity to sharpen his skills but is a great example of what a CMS should be.

Comment: @iambriansreed Perhaps - but if they don't have any skills before they start they will most likely just get lost attempting to edit themes and work with plugins.  Maybe I'm just old school.